# Cocoa-Touch – Opposite of ABGroupCreate (delete group)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

Is there any way that you can delete groups programatically? You can create them with `ABGroupCreate()` so logically there should be a delete function also? Or is that considered too hazardous (in a way that evil programmers can delete the user's groups?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove group members with ABGroupRemoveMember.

EDIT: Another idea: an ABGroup is an ABRecord, and you can remove an ABRecord with ABAddressBookRemoveRecord.

ANOTHER EDIT: And in fact see Apple's ABUIGroups example, which contains this code:

```
- (void)deleteGroup:(ABRecordRef)group fromAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)myAddressBook
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(myAddressBook, group, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(myAddressBook,&error);
}
```

So there you go.

Comment: So removing all group members in a group will consequently delete the group?

Comment: I've tried it now and removing all members of a group doesn't delete the group itself.

Comment: Well, an ABGroup is an ABRecord. But you can remove an ABRecord with ABAddressBookRemoveRecord. So I think you could actually do it. Adding that to my answer...

Comment: Added reference and sample code from Apple's ABUIGroups example.